# SQL Query to find number of tables available in Snowflake account(including all DB and schemas)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

SQL Query to get total number of tables available in Snowflake account(including all DB and schemas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query account_usage.tables or information_schema.tables views to find the total number of tables:

```
select count(*) from information_schema.tables;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/tables.html

```
select count(*) from snowflake.account_usage.tables;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/tables.html

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways:

1. You can query the view INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to find all tables of your current database. So: You have to write a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [database].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` for each of your databases, do a `UNION ALL` afterwards and `SUM()` your results per database to get the whole number of tables in all databases.
2. You can query the view ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES to find all tables and views of your account. One row represents one table. As ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES also contains views, you have to add a WHERE-Klause for the attribute TABLE_TYPE. Here you also have to keep in mind that you may have a latency of 90 minutes.
3. Run `SHOW TABLES IN ACCOUNT;` to see all tables

More infos about INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/tables.html

More infos about ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/tables.html

More infos about SHOW TABLES: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-tables.html

Note: For all three ways you can only see objects for which your current role has access privileges.